# How to bind dynamic text to a viewmodel other than using a hidden HTML control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I bind dynamic text to a view model?

I have a product page. Each variation of the product has a specific `SKU (stock keeping unit)`. For example (these are just examples):

- `Green shirt` would have a `SKU` of `greenshirt-001`
- `Blue shirt` would have a `SKU` of `blueshirt-001`

When the page loads up for the first time I load all the different colours for this product (`shirt`) and the default SKU, lets say the default SKU is `greenshirt-001`. So the user will see `greenshirt-001` as text on the page.

When the user selects another colour, for example the blue shirt, then I need it to go and some stuff on the server and display information about the blue shirt. Now `blueshirt-001` is displayed as text on the page.

There is an `add to cart` button also on the page. When the user clicks this button I want this variation of the product to be added to a shopping cart. I would like to retrieve the SKU that is currently being displayed to the user.

What is the best way of displaying this SKU to the user and retrieving it when the form is posted? I can't think of a way to display it as an HTML control and then to retrieve the value on the post other than using a hidden control?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
{
     <div class="product-details">
          <div class="sku">Item #: @Model.StockKeepingUnit.SKU</div>
          <div>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StockKeepingUnit.SKU)</div>
     </div>
     <div class="actions">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="test-button">Default</button>
     </div>
}
```

To make my life easy for now I added a button with an id of `test-button`. This is just for testing purposes before I write the server sided code. All that this button does is it changes the SKU to something else. For example it will change `greenshirt-001` to `blueshirt-001`. Currently I am only changing it on the hidden control.

Is there no way that I can ditch the hidden control and just bind it to another display control?

Here is my action method for the `HttpGet`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int productId)
{
     ProductViewModel model = await productTask.DetailsAsync(productId);
     if (model == null)
     {
          throw new HttpException(404, "404");
     }

     return View(model);
}
```

And here is partial code for my action method on the `HttpPost`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(ProductViewModel model)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          return View(model);
     }

     // Do something
     return View(model);
}
```

And my `jQuery` code to change the SKUs:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#test-button').click(function () {
               $("#StockKeepingUnit_SKU").val("blueshirt-001");
          });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Since your rendering the value as text in the view (I assume in a div?) then you can get the value using `var sku = $(yourDiv).text()` to avoid having to generate an extra hidden input

Comment: I need to return the vale when submitting the form. I need it to be bound so that I can retrieve it server side so that I can do stuff with it.

Comment: OK (I assumed you would be adding the item to the cart using ajax). Since you are doing a normal submit, then a hidden input will be necessary (or alternatively you could add the value to the forms route parameters)

Comment: Also you can always just use a `@Html.TextBoxFor()` and make it readonly (and delete the display text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a CSS-styled (readonly) textbox. For example remove the border and make the background the same as the surrounding space. This way it will be shown to the user (I understand this is intended), and it will also be POSTed with the FORM to the server.